# Printing time and saving it in file in C

Tags: c, time

I'm using ncurses and want to save time in file and print it. So i'm doing this:

```
typedef struct {
    struct tm* lastLoggedTime;
} Data_t;

void saveData(char *login, Data_t *Data)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(login, "wb");
    fwrite(Data, sizeof(Data_t), 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;
}

void loadSavedData(FILE *file, Data_t *Data)
{
    fread(Data, sizeof(Data_t), 1, file);
}

...

Data_t Data;
char strtime[32];
time_t timer;
time(&timer);
Data.lastLoggedTime = localtime(&timer);
saveData(login, &Data);

...

FILE *savefile = fopen(login, "rb");
loadSavedData(savefile, &Data);
strftime(strtime, 32, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", Data.lastLoggedTime);
printw("Last login: %s\n", strtime);
```

However, I get segmentation fault. GDB shows that in happens in strftime_l.c at line 562.

Comment: This may be result of some other error earlier in code (memory overwritten). Please use Valgrind, it should give you exact location where problem is.

Comment: The given code, with the proper includes and the lines at the bottom inside of `main`, works as expected.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write a structure out to file when the structure has pointers. Your struct to hold your data has a *pointer* to the time data, not the actual data.

If you want to save the data, you have to serialize the structure yourself.